# Javascript loop to detect when a series of minimum three identical numbers starts or ends

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
let data = [
  {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", value: 5.12002},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", value: 3.13285},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", value: 2.84637},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", value: 3.57281},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", value: 5.2812},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", value: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", value: null},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", value: null},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", value: 8.49232},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", value: 7.38261},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", value: 6.28182},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", value: null},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", value: null},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", value: null}
];
```

I want to create a function that loops through this array and returns all entries that end a series of minimum three lower (<10) or null values, **and** at the same time start a series of (minimum) three higher values (10). This should also work the other way around (return entries that end a series of three higher values (10) **and** at the same time start a streak of three lower or null values.)

In the example above, the desired output should be an array with the following two objects:

```
{timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", value: 10},
{timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", value: null}
```

So far have come up with the following function which is still incomplete and doesnt work. I am new to javascript a coding so some help would be really appreciated

```
jfdetection = () => {
  let result = [];
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (count === 3 && data.value === 10) {
      result.push(data)
      count = 0
    } else {
      if (data.value < 10) count ++
      else if (data.value === 10) count = 0
    }
   return result;
}}
```

Comment: Sorry you are both completely right. I have updated the array.

Comment: _"...function which is still incomplete and doesnt work"_ - Please explain both parts. What is missing? And why do you think it _"doesn't work"_?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get the `segment` in your code, but here's what I came up with quickly.

```
jfdetection = () => {
  let result = [];
  // Keep track of consecutive high or low values
  let highCount = 1;
  let lowCount = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Increment the counter if the previous value was similar, 
    // reset the counter if previous value was different.
    if (data[i].value === 10) {
      highCount = (data[i-1].value === 10) ? (highCount+1) : 1;
    } else if (data[i].value != 10) {
      lowCount = (data[i-1].value != 10) ? (lowCount+1) : 1;
    }

    // If we hit the required 3 similar values and there were 3 different values before, 
    // add to result
    if (highCount === 3 && lowCount >= 3) {
      result.push(data[i-2]);
    } else if (lowCount === 3 && highCount >= 3) {
      result.push(data[i-2]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works for the included example array ! However, I get a strange outcome when the array starts with a streak of for example four values of 10 in a row

Comment: @winecity, do you have some more examples and the wanted result?

Comment: @winecity That's true. I edited the answer so that both counters are initialized to 1. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The following maintains a six-slot frame of reference and when it matches one of the desired patterns, it adds the relevant item to the results.

```js
const data = [ {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", value: 5.12002}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", value: 3.13285}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", value: 2.84637}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", value: 3.57281}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", value: 5.2812}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", value: 8.49232}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", value: 7.38261}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", value: 6.28182}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", value: null} ]

const PATTERN = /lllhhh|hhhlll/

function process(data) {
  const results = []
  const frame = []

  for(let x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    frame.push(data[x].value === 10 ? 'h' : 'l')
    if(frame.length < 6) continue

    if(PATTERN.test(frame.join('')))
      results.push(data[x-2])
      
    frame.shift()    
  }

  return results
}

console.log(process(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ben's idea, you could map the whole input to a character string where each character corresponds to an entry. Then use a regular expression to find all occurrences of the pattern you are looking for:

```js
const regex = /000(?=111)|111(?=000)/g;
const peeks = (data) => Array.from(
    data.map(({value}) => "01"[+(value === 10)]).join("").matchAll(regex),
    match => data[match.index+3]
);

// demo
const data = [ {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", value: 5.12002}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", value: 3.13285}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", value: 2.84637}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", value: 3.57281}, {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", value: 5.2812}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", value: 10}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", value: 8.49232}, {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", value: 7.38261}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", value: 6.28182}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", value: null}, {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", value: null} ]

console.log(peeks(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look to wanted length of continuing same elements and check if the item is in a different group.

The loop consists of three parts:

- Check if a group check exists. If so, set `group` to an empty array.
- Push actual `item` to `group`.
- Check if `group` has the wanted length and if the last stored items has a different group, then push the first item of the `group` array to the result set.

Group sizes smaller than the wanted length are ignored.

Two helper function are

- `cp`, a comparison function, which takes an object, destructure `value` property and compares it to the wanted value,
- `last`, this returns from an array the last item.

```js
let data = [{ timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", value: 5.12002 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", value: 3.13285 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", value: 2.84637 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", value: 3.57281 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", value: 5.2812 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", value: 10 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", value: null }, { timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", value: null }, { timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", value: 8.49232 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", value: 7.38261 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", value: 6.28182 }, { timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", value: null }, { timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", value: null }, { timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", value: null }],
    group = [],
    result = [],
    length = 3,
    cp = ({ value } = {}) => value === 10,
    last = array => array[array.length - 1];

for (const item of data) {
    if (cp(group[0]) !== cp(item)) {
        group = [];
    }
    group.push(item);
    if (group.length === length && cp(group[0]) !== cp(last(result))) {
        result.push(group[0]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```